# Spaghetti plot with different colors for each subject in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

Here is what I have done so far, and the result plot is below:

```
set.seed(17)
require(ggplot2)
x = expand.grid(a=1:5, b=1:5)
x$c = rnorm(25)
png('test.png')
p = ggplot(x, aes(a, c, group=b)) + geom_line()
print(p)
dev.off()
savehistory()
```

[image]

The goal is to make each line to be displayed in a different color.

Comment: change `group=b` to `colour=b`.

Comment: @Arun sorry, that's not right. it will not group the data points into lines, but instead plot them as one line.

Comment: Not really. your `b` should be a `factor`. Try `colour = factor(b)`

Comment: @Arun I'd think you ought to put it as answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `ggplot2` comment gives you the right answer :

> You should coerce b to a factor and it as a color aes.

Using `lattice` no need to coerce b to factor:

```
library(lattice)
xyplot(c~a,data =x,groups=b,type='l')
```

[image]

Or using `latticeExtra` to get `ggplot2` theme:

```
library(latticeExtra)
xyplot(c~a,data =x,groups=b,type='l',
       par.settings = ggplot2like(),axis=axis.grid)
```

[image]